# Test works in selenium but not with default driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have this test

```
feature 'edit company', :js=>true do
  scenario 'edit company' do
    visit '/companies'
    page.has_content? company.name
    find('#edit_company_btn_1').click
...
```

This works without problems.  But when I remove the :js=>true part I get this error:

```
 Failure/Error: find('#update_btn_company').click
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass
```

Why is this working with one driver but not with the other?

Comment: If your scenario needs JavaScript, then you need to use Selenium which has support for that (thus the `:js=>true`). If your page is using JavaScript and you use the default web driver, then there is no JS support, so it will fail.

Comment: Yup I completely understand that.  But, that page requires no javascript whatsoever...  He says he can't find the #update_btn_company (returns nil), but it does find it.